# Kubernetes working locally fine with Minikube but when deploying in the GKE can't able to access external ip

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I need to convert docker-compose to Kubernetes.yml and needs to deploy to GKE.

To achieve this, I have converted docker-compose.yml file to kuberntes.yml with Kompose using below command

```
kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml -o kubernetes.yml and once after file generating.
```

I ran yaml with kubectl apply -f Kubernetes.yml with Minikube and its working fine locally and I am able to access load balancing ip in the browser.

But when I deploy in the GKE. Can't access the external ip. Below is the services when I run kubectl get svc

```
NAME                       TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)          AGE
backend                    ClusterIP      10.32.129.17    <none>         8000/TCP         42m
cleverstack-auth-service   LoadBalancer   10.32.131.62    34.134.47.16   8080:30295/TCP   42m
kubernetes                 ClusterIP      10.32.128.1     <none>         443/TCP          43m
proxy                      ClusterIP      10.32.130.232   <none>         8080/TCP         42m
redis                      ClusterIP      10.32.131.143   <none>         6379/TCP         42m
```

If I try to access 34.134.47.16:8080 can't connect. Am I missing anything?

```
    apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: cleverstack-auth-service
  annotations:
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: localhost
spec:
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: proxy
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
---

apiVersion: v1
items:
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml -o kubernetes1.yml
        kompose.version: 1.27.0 (HEAD)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: backend
      name: backend
    spec:
      ports:
        - name: "8000"
          port: 8000
          targetPort: 8000
      selector:
        io.kompose.service: backend
    status:
      loadBalancer: {}
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml -o kubernetes1.yml
        kompose.version: 1.27.0 (HEAD)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: proxy
      name: proxy
    spec:
      ports:
        - name: "80"
          port: 80
          targetPort: 8080
      selector:
        io.kompose.service: proxy
    status:
      loadBalancer: {}
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml -o kubernetes1.yml
        kompose.version: 1.27.0 (HEAD)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: redis
      name: redis
    spec:
      ports:
        - name: "6379"
          port: 6379
          targetPort: 6379
      selector:
        io.kompose.service: redis
    status:
      loadBalancer: {}
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml -o kubernetes1.yml
        kompose.version: 1.27.0 (HEAD)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: backend
      name: backend
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          io.kompose.service: backend
      strategy:
        type: Recreate
      template:
        metadata:
          annotations:
            kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml -o kubernetes1.yml
            kompose.version: 1.27.0 (HEAD)
          creationTimestamp: null
          labels:
            io.kompose.network/cs-network: "true"
            io.kompose.service: backend
        spec:
          containers:
            - args:
                - gunicorn
                - cleverstack.wsgi:application
                - --bind
                - 0.0.0.0:8000
                - --env
                - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=cleverstack.settings
              env:
                - name: DEBUG
                  value: "True"
              image: asia.gcr.io/project/docker-image:latest
              name: cleverstack-auth-backend
              ports:
                - containerPort: 8000
              resources: {}
              volumeMounts:
                - mountPath: /home/cs-user/cs-backend/static
                  name: static-volume
                - mountPath: /home/cs-user/cs-backend/media
                  name: media-volume
          restartPolicy: Always
          volumes:
            - name: static-volume
              persistentVolumeClaim:
                claimName: static-volume
            - name: media-volume
              persistentVolumeClaim:
                claimName: media-volume
    status: {}
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: static-volume
      name: static-volume
    spec:
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 100Mi
    status: {}
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: media-volume
      name: media-volume
    spec:
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 100Mi
    status: {}
  - apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    kind: NetworkPolicy
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      name: cs-network
    spec:
      ingress:
        - from:
            - podSelector:
                matchLabels:
                  io.kompose.network/cs-network: "true"
      podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          io.kompose.network/cs-network: "true"
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml -o kubernetes1.yml
        kompose.version: 1.27.0 (HEAD)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: celery
      name: celery
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          io.kompose.service: celery
      strategy:
        type: Recreate
      template:
        metadata:
          annotations:
            kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml -o kubernetes1.yml
            kompose.version: 1.27.0 (HEAD)
          creationTimestamp: null
          labels:
            io.kompose.network/cs-network: "true"
            io.kompose.service: celery
        spec:
          containers:
            - args:
                - celery
                - -A
                - cleverstack
                - worker
                - -l
                - info
              env:
                - name: DEBUG
                  value: "True"
              image: asia.gcr.io/project/docker-image:latest
              name: celery
              resources: {}
              volumeMounts:
                - mountPath: /home/cs-user/cs-celery
                  name: celery-volume
          restartPolicy: Always
          volumes:
            - name: celery-volume
              persistentVolumeClaim:
                claimName: celery-volume
    status: {}
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: celery-volume
      name: celery-volume
    spec:
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 100Mi
    status: {}
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml -o kubernetes1.yml
        kompose.version: 1.27.0 (HEAD)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: celery-beat
      name: celery-beat
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          io.kompose.service: celery-beat
      strategy:
        type: Recreate
      template:
        metadata:
          annotations:
            kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml -o kubernetes1.yml
            kompose.version: 1.27.0 (HEAD)
          creationTimestamp: null
          labels:
            io.kompose.network/cs-network: "true"
            io.kompose.service: celery-beat
        spec:
          containers:
            - args:
                - celery
                - -A
                - cleverstack
                - worker
                - -l
                - info
              env:
                - name: DEBUG
                  value: "True"
              image: asia.gcr.io/project/docker-image:latest
              name: celery-beat
              resources: {}
              volumeMounts:
                - mountPath: /home/cs-user/cs-celery_beat
                  name: celery-beat-volume
          restartPolicy: Always
          volumes:
            - name: celery-beat-volume
              persistentVolumeClaim:
                claimName: celery-beat-volume
    status: {}
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: celery-beat-volume
      name: celery-beat-volume
    spec:
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 100Mi
    status: {}
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml -o kubernetes1.yml
        kompose.version: 1.27.0 (HEAD)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: proxy
      name: proxy
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          io.kompose.service: proxy
      strategy: {}
      template:
        metadata:
          annotations:
            kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml -o kubernetes1.yml
            kompose.version: 1.27.0 (HEAD)
          creationTimestamp: null
          labels:
            io.kompose.network/cs-network: "true"
            io.kompose.service: proxy
        spec:
          containers:
            - image: asia.gcr.io/project/docker-image:latest
              name: cleverstack-auth-proxy
              ports:
                - containerPort: 8080
              resources: {}
          restartPolicy: Always
    status: {}
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml -o kubernetes1.yml
        kompose.version: 1.27.0 (HEAD)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: redis
      name: redis
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          io.kompose.service: redis
      strategy: {}
      template:
        metadata:
          annotations:
            kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml -o kubernetes1.yml
            kompose.version: 1.27.0 (HEAD)
          creationTimestamp: null
          labels:
            io.kompose.network/cs-network: "true"
            io.kompose.service: redis
        spec:
          containers:
            - args:
                - redis-server
              image: redis
              name: redis
              ports:
                - containerPort: 6379
              resources: {}
          restartPolicy: Always
    status: {}
kind: List
metadata: {}
```

Comment: Any change you can post your `kubernetes.yml` contents?

Comment: @GariSingh I have added the Kubernetes.yml. Kindly please look into that once. 

And I have removed environmental variables from the code and also images.

Comment: Looks like the NetworkPolicy is blocking all external traffic and only allows traffic from within the cluster itself.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possible places you can look at:

1. Make sure that the backend for the LB is healthy as per the LB.
2. Make sure there is security group rule which allows ingress traffic from LB to the cluster node where you pod is running.